# Filter nodes by date published

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

How can I show all nodes BUT the latest one published using Views? So far I can only filter them by a specific date, which is no good. 
Thanks!

Comment: Can they be sorted in descending order by published date?

Comment: yes, they can, but i'd like to hide just the latest one node

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok to sort the content by published date in descending order, you can set the View pager offset to 1 to exclude the first item which would be the latest one.